# Integrating Crittercisim SDK in workspace with multiple projects

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, crittercism

My workspace has a structure such as depicted below:

- MultipleProjects.xcworkspace
- CrittercismSDK
- Project1
- Project2
- Project3
- :
- Projectn

I've tried using this KB article without any luck: http://support.crittercism.com/articles/knowledge_base/Integrate-with-multiple-xcode-projects

Essentially, I seek to share the CrittercisimSDK  dependencies throughout my workspace.
Thus, it must be configured so that the library may be utilized within any project in our 
workspace without the necessity to replicate the SDK for each (sub)project within the workspace.

I've spent a great deal of time researching this configuration for this SDK with out much luck.
I've explored Xcode environment variables (I was unable to locate an Xcode environmental variable defining the ROOT workspace path; only paths relative to a respective project).

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I utilized was to subclass the entire Crittercism SDK and create a static library which can be consumed by any of the child projects within the workspace.